# If a function is odd/even, then its best polynomial approximation is also odd/even.

Tags: real-analysis, approximation-theory, chebyshev-polynomials

If $f$ ∈ $C([a,b])$ is an even/odd function, then show that the best approximation among the polynomials of degree n is also even/odd.

I'm almost certain that to show this directly, you should use the Chebyshev Equioscillation Theorem.

I start by assuming that for some function $f$ ∈ $C([a,b])$, the best polynomial approximation of degree n is $P$. Then, by the theorem,
$f$(x<sub>i</sub>) - $P$(x<sub>i</sub>) = (-1)<sup>i</sup>||$f$ - $P$||<sub>∞</sub> for at least n+2 many points in [a,b].

If $f$ is even, then $f$(x<sub>i</sub>) = $f$(-x<sub>i</sub>), and if $f$ is an odd function, then $f$(x<sub>i</sub>) = - $f$(-x<sub>i</sub>)

I just can't piece this stuff together though

EDIT:
It was pointed out that the problem doesn't make much sense unless the interval [a,b] is actually [a,-a]. The problem, however, doesn't address this, sadly.

Comment: I'm an outsider to this field, but if $a\ne-b$, I don't believe the claim.

Comment: If $a \not = -b$ then the concept of even or odd function on $[a,b]$ is undefined. The question should be for $f \in C ([-a,a])$; I would edit the original post, but I am running into the idiotic 6 character minimum for edits.

Comment: @mathguy The typesetting in the post is *really* weird; if you cleaned it up too, you'd surely exceed the 6char limit. But I'm really not convinced that the interval should be changed by anyone but the OP; I'd like them to weigh in on that.

Comment: Just to reiterate my own comment and support the others, what could it possibly mean to say that a function defined on $[0,b]$ is odd or even?

Comment: That's actually a really good point... The book doesn't specify anything other than what I put in the question :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume $a = -b$, and to introduce some notation, fix a positive integer $m$, let $P_m$ denote the subsapce of polynomial functions in $C[a,b]$ of degree at most $m$, and for any $f \in C[a,b]$, let $f_m$ denote the element of $P_m$ that is closest to $f$ in the supremum norm.  (By a bunch of complicated theorems, you know such an element exists, and that it is unique.  *This is the key to at least one way of doing the exercise.*  In other words, you can leverage the known uniqueness of the best approximation into a fairly simple proof of the result.)

Here is a strategy to the problem.

- If $f$ is even, define $p \in P_m$ by declaring for all $x \in [a,b]$ that $p(x) = (1/2)(f_m(x) + f_m(-x))$.  Verify that $p$ thus defined is indeed an element of $P_m$ and that $p$ is even.  Prove that $\|f - p\| \leq \|f - f_m\|$.  It follows from the uniqueness property mentioned above that $f_m = p$.
- If $f$ is odd, follow the same program, but with $p$ defined by $p(x) = (1/2)(f_m(x) - f_m(-x))$.

For a little more guidance on (1).

**Why $p$ is in $P_m$.**  Because $f_m$ is in $P_m$ by definition and it is generally true that whenever $g(x)$ is a polynomial, the function $g(-x)$ is a polynomial of the same degree, it follows that $f_m(x)$ and $f_m(-x)$ are both polynomials of degree at most $m$, and hence (because $P_m$ is a subspace of $C[a,b]$) that $p$ thus defined is a polynomial of degree at most $m$.

**Why $p$ is even.**  The fact that $p$ is even is just a simple computation from the definition.  (It doesn't depend in any way on $f_m$ being a polynomial. If $g$ is any element of $C[a,b]$, the function $(1/2)(g(x) + g(-x))$ is even.)

**Why $\|f - p\| \leq \|f - f_m\|$.**  This can be seen from a short computation.
Fix $t \in [a,b]$.  Note that
\begin{align}
|f(t) - p(t)| & = |f(t) - (1/2)(f_m(t) + f_m(-t))| \\ 
& = (1/2) |2f(t) - f_m(t) - f_m(-t)| \\
& \leq (1/2) (|f(t) - f_m(t)| + |f(t) - f_m(-t)|) \\
& = (1/2) (|f(t) - f_m(t)| + |f(-t) - f_m(-t)|),
\end{align}
where in the last line we used the fact that $f$ is even to replace $f(t)$ with $f(-t)$.  Now note that by definition of the norm we have $|f(t) - f_m(t)| \leq \|f - f_m\|$, and also that $|f(-t) - f_m(-t)| \leq \|f - f_m\|$ (this latter inference is where we use the fact that $a = -b$, because we need to know that $-t$ is also in $[a,b]$ to deduce that $|f(-t) - f_m(-t)| \leq \sup_{s \in [a,b]} |f(s) - f_m(s)| = \|f - f_m\|$).  We can therefore deduce from the chain of above inequalities and equalities that $|f(t) - p(t)| \leq \|f - f_m\|$.  Since this holds for all $t \in [a,b]$, we deduce that $\|f - p\| \leq \|f - f_m\|$ as desired.

**We can generalize this exercise a little bit.**   Suppose $V$ is a normed vector space and $W$ a subspace of $V$.  Suppose further that $T: V \to V$ is a linear map with the property that (1) $T \circ T$ is the identity, (2) $T$ preserves the norm (i.e. for all $v \in V$ one has $\|T(v)\| = \|v\|$), and (3) $W$ is invariant under $T$ (i.e. for all $w \in W$, $T(w) \in W$).  Suppose finally that $v \in V$ is a fixed element of $V$ and that $T(v) = v$.

Theorem: under these hypotheses, if there is a unique element $w$ of $W$ such that $\|v - w\| = \inf_{z \in W} \|v - z\|$, then one has $T(w) = w$.

Proof: let $w' = (1/2)(w + T(w))$.  Our hypotheses imply that $w' \in W$ and that $T(w') = w'$.  And clearly $\|v - w'\| = (1/2) \|v - w + v - T(w)\| \leq (1/2) (\|v - w\| + \|v  - T(w)\|)$.  But since $T(v) = v$ and $T$ is linear and norm-preserving, we know that $\|v - T(w)\| = \|T(v) - T(w)\| = \|T(v - w)\| = \|v - w\|$, and it follows that $\|v - w'\| \leq \|v - w\|$ and hence (from uniqueness) that $w = w'$. End of proof.

We recover the result above by taking $V = C[-b,b]$, $W = P_m$, and $T$ the map $f(x) \mapsto f(-x)$ (in the even case) or $f(x) \mapsto -f(-x)$ (in the odd case).